# Append Onclick Function on Gravity Form Submit Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onclick

[EDIT: I first thought I had to make it this way but could style the first form in a way where I didnt have to display the second form, so no answer needed anymore.]

I have two Gravity Forms and want to add the data filled in the first when submitting/clicking on the second.
I've hidden the first submit button and copied the onClick function of the first form and put in in a JS function:

```
function getFormData() {
  if(window["gf_submitting_52"]){return false;}  if( !jQuery("#gform_52")[0].checkValidity || jQuery("#gform_52")[0].checkValidity()){window["gf_submitting_52"]=true;}
}
```

Now I thought I could just append this function to the onClick function for the second submit Button so I've tried:

```
jQuery('#gform_submit_button_53').click(getFormData());
```

and

```
jQuery('#gform_submit_button_53').addEEventListener('click','getFormData());
```

But both didn't seem to work.
Anybody got any ideas?
I've put everything in a document onready function and placed the JS in the footer of my page.

The Markup of the first Button:

```
<input type='submit' id='gform_submit_button_52' class='gform_button button' value='SENDEN' tabindex='6' onclick='if(window["gf_submitting_52"]){return false;}  if( !jQuery("#gform_52")[0].checkValidity || jQuery("#gform_52")[0].checkValidity()){window["gf_submitting_52"]=true;}  ' onkeypress='if( event.keyCode == 13 ){ if(window["gf_submitting_52"]){return false;} if( !jQuery("#gform_52")[0].checkValidity || jQuery("#gform_52")[0].checkValidity()){window["gf_submitting_52"]=true;}  jQuery("#gform_52").trigger("submit",[true]); }' />
```

After that there's a bunch of hidden input types for the values for the fields I've used.

Comment: try using `jQuery('#gform_submit_button_53').on('click', getFormData);` instead to set the event listener correctly. Are you sure your getFormData function doesn't return any error? is anything showed in the console?

Comment: just tried it, no console errors, it only validates the second form and the values of the first form arent in the mail as well.

Comment: just tried calling it in the console and it says its not defined, however it is added in the source code

Comment: can you add the code where you define your form?

Comment: You mean the whole form? It's a gravity form, there's also an onKeyEvent on the buttom, I'll add the markup from the button I would have done it with plain html form but I had to use Gravity forms for certain reasons...

Comment: The id of the button you added here is "gform_submit_button_52" but you set the listener on "gform_submit_button_53"

Comment: Yea because I want to add the onClick Event from Button 52 to the gform_submit_button_53, so that the second button submits both, form 52 and 53 values

Comment: A submit button can't submit 2 forms at the same time... Even if you trigger the on click of the 1st submit at the same time, only 1 form data can be sent at a time. You are going to need to make thoses 2 forms in one, or add hidden fields in the second form that copy the ones of the 1st form if you want to do something like this.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I can't put them in one because the html markup doesnt allow  it. So I have to add hidden fields. Can you give a short direction how I can achieve this with Jquery?

Comment: I think the best way to achieve it would be to catch the on change events of the fields of the 1st form in jquery and update the values of the fields of the second form every time the event is triggered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160675/discussion-between-erik7-and-liora-haydont).

Comment: Have you looked at option 4 here: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_submit_button/